# a json.getString() function returns a String of strange format so that It can't be compared to string of seemingly same value

Tags: json

When comparing the output of json.getString() to a string of same value i manually inputted into a json file, it's a false comparison.

```
println("-");
   println(jsonScene.getString("value"));
   println(jsonScene.getString("value") == "-");
```

Outputs

```
-
-
false
```

The same value is printed but when compared, it's false but should be true.

Comment: What is your `"-".charCodeAt(0)` for these strings? What happens if you compare them after `trim()`-ming both?

Answer (score 1):

Remember in Processing (Java) you need to compare Strings using [`equals()`](https://processing.org/reference/String_equals_.html):

> Compares two strings to see if they are the same. This method is necessary because it's not possible to compare strings using the equality operator (==). Returns true if the strings are the same and false if they are not.

For example:

```java
println(jsonScene.getString("value").equals("-"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I forgot this simple rule!

Answer (score 0):

- Check the `.charCodeAt(0)` for both strings
- `.trim()` both of them before the comparison
- Check that `typeof jsonScene.getString("value") === "string"` (it could be an object with custom `toString()` defined)

Comment: Thank you, all good suggestions
- char code was as expected
- trim() didn't fix the problem, seemingly had no effect
- the return type is definitely a string

Comment: I compared the charCode at index 0 for both strings, and they were the same. Both were only 1 character (charAt(1) threw an error), their chars are the same, but as Strings they are not - I will code a workaround, thank you